# Ger around "Refused to connect to <URL> because it violates the CSP" in the devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, content-security-policy

I'm currently on [news.ycombinator.com](https://news.ycombinator.com).

I'd like to run the following code in my devtools:

```js
const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/upload", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({
       html: document.documentElement.outerHTML,
  })
});
await response.json();
```

However, I get the error:

> Refused to connect to 'http://localhost:3000/api/upload' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Is there a way to work around this in the dev tools, or am I forbidden from making requests to any external API from the devtools?

Comment: no the CSP header on `news.ycombinator.com` is blocking your fetch. Just open dev tools in empty tab and you should be good.

Comment: Why aren't you just making requests from the server to get content? And HTML is not `application/json`.

Comment: @YK1 Then `document.documentElement.outerHTML` won't work.

Comment: @Foobar: `fetch('news.ycombinator.com')` first, parse the HTML and then upload to your API.